# Redis xstream and hashmap performance gap acrosss network and how to improve xstream performance

Tags: redis

I did some benchmarks of xstream and hashmap across different machines(one read/write from/to another machine).

I use Jedis(Java), the xstream command I use is

```
val response = jedis.xreadGroup("my-group", "consumer1",
          count=4, block=1, noAck=false, new SimpleEntry(streamName, StreamEntryID.UNRECEIVED_ENTRY))
```

and hashmap command is just

```
jedis.keys("*")
```

I tried some data, when it is small (1k char string in test), their cost are both <1ms.

But when it is larger (100k char string in test), I got following result

```
2021-07-02 09:37:45 INFO  RedisBaseline$:16 - put xstream len 100000 time elapsed [10.760028 ms]
2021-07-02 09:37:45 INFO  RedisBaseline$:16 - put hashmap len 100000 time elapsed [12.127884 ms]
2021-07-02 09:37:45 INFO  RedisBaseline$:16 - get hashmap len 100000 time elapsed [0.448862 ms]
2021-07-02 09:37:45 INFO  RedisBaseline$:16 - read xstream len 100000 time elapsed [67.994358 ms]
```

there is an large gap between hashmap read and xstream read. (I also did this test on same machine but all results are <1ms after stable)

So is there a brief introduction about how they work internally? And why xstream is slower? is it due to hashmap index? is there any improvement available?

Comment: What are the exact commands you used to read hash and stream? If it's batch-reading, what's the batch size?

Comment: @for_stack I added the command detail in question.